df.show() shows empty dataframe after selection a field from a json file which is not null?

SparkSession initiation

I am using pyspark version 3.2.0
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,max,month, unix_timestamp,floor
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,monotonically_increasing_id
import logging
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

from all_items_data_loropiana import items_data_all_orders

spark1 = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName("book_and_pack")\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/")\
    .config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True)\
    .config('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)\
    .config("inferSchema",True)\
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.sampleSize", 50000)\
    .config('spark.jars.packages','org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.2')\
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties")\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()

logger = logging.getLogger("org.mongodb.spark.MongsoInferSchema")
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

2.Data Schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("orderNumber", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Orderstate", ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("state", StringType(), True),
            StructField("modifiedAt", StructType([StructField("$date", StringType(), True)]), True)
        ])
    ), True)
])

3.Selecting data from json file
ordersips_df=spark.read.json("myfile.json")
df=ordersips_df.select("Orderstate")

the output is :
df.show() // return null
I didn't get out the problem yet, but i tried to pass the schema manually if it causes the problem by any chance, but it doesn't solve the problem. thanks

What is the output of ordersips_df.show(1)?

@smurphy I updated spark version from 3.2.0 to 3.5.2 and the problem disappeared, i still don't get the cause of the problem.

It's unlikely that this is an issue with show(), rather the error probably happens when the data is read. Try logger.info(ordersips_df.select("Orderstate").count()) to check if the column is empty, and make sure to read the JSON data with support for multiline rows enabled:
ordersips_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("myfile.json")

Finally, you should try displaying the entire dataframe to verify the integrity of the data and post the output if possible.

I updated spark version from 3.2.0 to 3.5.2 and the problem disappeared, i still don't get the cause of the problem
